# Python - Build minimal 'front-end' to run a sklearn function

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm wondering what the easiest way is to built a bare-bones web-based 'form' that would allow for a user to run text against a function. If possible, I'd like to avoid a full web-development kit such as Flask.

All that is needed is a single text box that takes in a strong of text. Upon clicking 'submit', the text is run against a function and the resulting prediction is returned on the screen. I'm envisioning something like the below:

[image: Sample image]

I'm playing around the Bokeh package and attempting to run a Bokeh server that has callbacks associated with running the Python function, but wanted to make sure it's feasible before devoting too much time into it.

Any other packages or ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Flask is relatively lightweight, at least as far as web frameworks go, and it takes care of lots of details for you. Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: Does this have to be run with a server, or are you open to creating a simple GUI that achieves the same thing? If so, this could very, very trivially be done in PyQt.

Comment: @Chris Honestly, I haven't done much exploration into Flask, but it seems a bit overkill for the task at hand. If it's not though, I will definitely explore it.

Comment: @PrestonH A server would be preferable, though a GUI could work in the interim. Thank you - I'll look into PyQt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nearly trivial Bokeh application to write:

```
# app.py 

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button, Div, TextInput

input = TextInput(placeholder="Enter sentence here ...")
button = Button(label="Submit")
result = Div()

def predict():
    # your real sklearn code goes here
    if len(input.value) % 2:
        result.text = "ODD"
    else:
        result.text = "EVEN"

button.on_click(predict)

curdoc().add_root(widgetbox(input, button, result))
```

---

If you run this with `bokeh serve --show app.py` you will get a responsive web application in your browser, that returns:

[image: odd prediction]

for an "odd length" submission and

[image: even prediction]

for an "even length" submission.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this, though trivial! I figured it should be easy, but everything I came across either in documentation, SO or other examples had some element of plotting in it so I began to doubt. Now it's time for me to learn Bokeh ground-up the right way...

Comment: There is a "non-plotting" example in the [tutorial notebooks](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/bokeh/bokeh-notebooks/blob/master/tutorial/00%20-%20intro.ipynb), but perhaps one could be added to the main docs site too. Feel free to open an issue on GH if you have any suggestions to improve the docs.